# Why are random recruiters showing up in my "Contacts" in LinkedIn?

Tags: linkedin

When I view my connections on LinkedIn dozens of random recruiters and other miscellaneous people I have never heard of show up at the head of the list as "contacts". Why is this? How do I stop it from happening?

Comment: This is not the support forum for any social media.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about navigating the workplace.

Comment: One of many reasons I concluded that linkedin had stopped having any value to me.

Answer (score 3):

Although this isn't strictly to do with the workplace, let's give an answer because it's a common question by job seekers.

These recruiters are asking to be your friends because recruiters live by their connections. Their whole point is to find people to fill jobs, and the more people they can contact the more successful they are likely to be.

The less scrupulous recruiters want to be your friends because you might be someone they are looking for (statistically unlikely) but also because once they are your friend they can see all your friends, and repeat the procedure on them. They got to you because they did the process on one of your friends at some point.

There are more ethical recruiters who will only contact you if they have a job that they actually believe might be one you are looking for. They will usually say so in the first contact message (though not all the ones who say so are telling the truth). If you are looking for a job it is not always a good idea to blanket decline all unsolicited contacts.

To stop them: decline all invitations from people you don't know, and ask your friends to do the same. If you accept any, unfriend them as soon as you are done.

Comment: I typically pick "ignore" when someone I don't know, like a recruiter, tries to connect to me. But from what you are saying they somehow can become my "contact" anyway? They become a "contact" by unilaterally sending me an unsolicited request to connect?

Comment: @Socrates My guess would be that you see them as a potential contact in case you want to get in touch with them, but other people do not see them as one of your "connections."

Comment: Be aware that they will use YOUR connections to further expand their network.  You may not get any benefit out of it at all.

Comment: @JaneS I believe I said that in the the third paragraph.

Comment: @DJClayworth Whoops, so you did :)  Sorry!  Still drinking my first coffee of the day! :)